# Where should the python babel mapping configuration file be placed or named for standalone script?

Tags: python, configuration, internationalization, python-babel

I am currently trying to use Babel to generate a set of static html pages in different languages using Jinja2 within a simple script (not as part of a web app)

I am at the point where I need to extract the messages for translation and I know that I am supposed to modify the Babel mapping configuration file to understand Jinja2 templates.Since I am using the commandline tool, I assume I need to create the mapping file myself.

However, I can't seem to find in the [documentation](http://babel.edgewall.org/wiki/Documentation/messages.html) what the mapping configuration file should be named and where it should be placed. All I know is that I need to place the following:

```
[jinja2: **/templates/**.html]
encoding = utf-8
```

into the mapping file according to the Jinja2 documentation. Has anyone done something similar or know what the mapping configuration file should be? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify the location of the configuration file with [`-c <filename>`](https://www.irif.fr/%7Ejch/software/babel/babeld.html).

Comment: Thanks, should have paid more attention to the options.

Comment: This answer is incorrect. `-c` is related to comments. The link in this answer links to a different program,`babeld`, which is an "ad-hoc network routing daemon." See my answer below for the correct flag for specifying the mapping configuration file.

Answer (score 2):

Mapping file location is read from setup.cfg file (generated by Distutils), in the section "extract_messages". In this section you must add setting named `mapping_file`, which should point to Your mapping file.

Example:

This tells Babel to look for mapping file named `message-extraction.ini` in package directory.

```
[extract_messages]
# some default options
# ..
mapping_file = message-extraction.ini
```

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the path to the mapping configuration file for `extract_messages` using [-F](https://babel.pocoo.org/en/latest/setup.html?highlight=configuration#id1). For example, my mapping configuration is in `babel.cfg`, located at the root of my project. When extracting messages, I run:

```
pybabel extract -F babel.cfg ...
```